# Passing input form value to URL variable

Tags: django

I need to pass the form input entered by the user to the URL variable in Django

```
<form>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="ticker" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <a her="{% url 'Main:search' %}" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

The input value needs to be passed as a variable in the following URL logic

`"{% url 'Main:search' %}"`

`urls.py`

```
app_name = 'Main'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name='index'),
        path('search/<ticker>', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def search(request, ticker):
    ticker = ticker.upper()
    result = Symbol.objects.filter(symbol=ticker).first()
    if result is not None:
        return redirect('Symbol:index', ticker=ticker)
    else:
        return render(request, 'symbol_not_found.html')
```

Comment: `<a her="{% url 'Main:search' %}"` What is `her=`?  Did you mean `href=`?

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

`the_view.html`:

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="ticker" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <a herf="{% url 'Main:search' ticker %}" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`urls.py`

```
app_name = 'Main'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name='index'),
        path('search/<str:ticker>', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

def search(request, ticker):
    result = get_list_or_404(Symbol, symbol=ticker) # If list is empty 404
    result = result[0] # get the first element in the list
    return render(request, reverse('Symbol:index',args=(ticker=ticker,)))
```

To get more info, you should make the small intro project in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/), especially [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial04/).

Comment: I get the following error `Reverse for 'search' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<ticker>[^/]+)\\Z']`

Comment: first edit the function name in views, I misspelled it, it is `search` not `results`